# A = list не одно и тоже, что и A = []?

Tags: python, python-3.x

код ниже складывает строки из эксель файла во вложенный список.
Если во второй строке объявлять массив как `prepared_data = list`
Получаю ошибку `TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`
Если объявлять как в коде, то все работает
В чем разница между a = list и a = []? Python 3.7

```
def collection_data(self, excel_data):
        prepared_data = []
        for index, row in excel_data.iterrows():
            frame_to_send = []
            for i in range(3):
                frame_to_send.append(row[i])
            prepared_data.append(frame_to_send)
        print(prepared_data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

list - это встроенная функция и класс языка питон, а не инициализатор для списка. Создать объект класса - это вызвать конструктор, а не присвоить имя класса переменной:

```
prepared_data=list()
```

Вы целые числа инициализируете с помощью выражения?

```
i = int
```